# How to avoid long enum constants in PyQt6

Tags: pyqt6

Recently I started a new PyQt project. I've been using PyQt5 for years, but to stay modern I thought I'd switch to PyQt6.

Come to find out that enum constants got really verbose in PyQt6. How about a concrete example?

**PyQt5**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCompleter

completer = QCompleter()
completer.setCaseSensitivity(False)
completer.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
```

**PyQt6**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCompleter

completer = QCompleter()
completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive)
completer.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.CompletionMode.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
```

Constants are now getting ridiculously long to type. Has anybody come up with a design pattern to overcome this inconvenience?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no recommended solution. Considering that sometimes we even import just the submodules, it *has* become quite ridiculous: consider trying an `if` comparison like the above, but also adding the submodule... Besides, it's not the typing that worries me, but the readability. I used to work with submodule namespaces, but I lately switched to direct class imports (even with wildcards, as I doubt that it really affects that much), which helped readability with the known verbosity of Qt namings (which is a good thing, usually), but this change is really killing it.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of solutions ranked to my personal preference:

1. Learn to live with it.
2. Switch to PySide6.
3. Try to learn to live with it again.
4. Become a monk and never touch a computer again.
5. Assign the enum to a short named variable: `cm = QCompleter.CompletionMode`.

Comment: Note that PySide has [switched](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/considerations.html#newenumsystem) to actual Python enums since PySide 6.3, and it's possible that sooner or later it will require full namespace too just like PyQt. The documentation doesn't explicitly say that it *will* happen, but not only it says that it's the recommended way, but also that it is "recommended for the future".

Comment: definitely 4. this is the last time you'll hear from me.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not recommended in general, but here a solution for simple apps that are supposed to run both with PyQt5 and PyQt6:

```
USE_PYQT6 = True

if USE_PYQT6:
    from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
    from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QCompleter

    def flatten_enum_namespaces(*classes):
        for cls in classes:
            for prop in dir(cls):
                attr = getattr(cls, prop)
                if type(attr).__name__ == 'EnumType':
                    for k, v in attr.__members__.items():
                        setattr(cls, k, v)

    flatten_enum_namespaces(Qt, QCompleter)  # add more classes as needed
else:
    from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCompleter

completer = QCompleter()
completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
completer.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
```

Comment: This code won't work with classes such as [QColorSpace](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcolorspace.html), [QMediaFormat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmediaformat.html), [QNetworkInformation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnetworkinformation.html), etc which have multiple enums with identical member names within the same namespace. Such enum members can *only* be safely accessed using fully scoped names. This issue affects *all* PyQt6 apps, not just so-called "simple" ones. It's a total pain, but we are stuck with it now, and there's no point pretending otherwise.

Comment: @ekhumoro It wasn't my intention to pretend anything, all I know is that I currently have an application that uses this approach, and it works fine both in PyQt5 and PyQt6. But yes, I'm very aware of the limitations. Concerning QColorSpace, after "flattening" color constants like "Qt.red" etc. work fine also in PyQt6, and that's about what I meant with "simple apps".